# Cannot read property 'createText' of null

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am very new to angular. I have a modal that pops up clicking a button and as I need this(button and modal) in several other places and I have created a separate component for that but unfortunately I am getting the above-mentioned error.

modal.component

```js
export class NotificationModalComponent {
    
    msgRef: BsModalRef;


  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService ) { }
    getNotify(template?:TemplateRef<any>){
    this.msgRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }
```

```html
<button (click)="popsModal('msgmodal')">
<ng-template #msgmodal>
  <div class="modal-body text-center">
    <h3>Allow Notifications</h3>
    <small>Click allow to get push notifications</small>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

otherParentComponet

```
<app-modal></app-modal>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createText' of null in ngx-bootstrap with angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759104/error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-createtext-of-null-in-ngx-bootstrap-with)

Comment: No that was for different context

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz to reproduce the issue?